# class property: Error: Illegal symbol for property access

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I have this variable, function, property combination

```
ffieldIntegerPrivate:Integer;
function getFieldIntegerPrivate:Integer;
class property fieldIntegerPrivate:Integer read getFieldIntegerPrivate;
```

and in the implementation I have

```
function TMyClass.getFieldIntegerPrivate:Integer;
begin
    Result := ffieldIntegerPrivate;
end;
```

I get error: Error: Illegal symbol for property access

What could be the cause of this error?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I found the answer myself. The function needs the keyword "static" added.

Comment: Using class completion (Ctrl+Shift+C) you will have a good hint: `class var ffieldIntegerPrivate:Integer;` and `class function getFieldIntegerPrivate:Integer; static;`

Comment: Class completion works very nice. I didn't know about that. A cool feature.

Comment: It's full of stars(strikeout) cool features :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class property` can only read `class var`.

Answer (score 2):

The function needs the keyword static added.

function getFieldIntegerPrivate:Integer;static;